# Egit hooks do not get triggered

Tags: git, githooks, egit, jgit

I have a git repo with a pre-commit hook that intentionally fails 100% of the time.

```
cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
> exit 1
```

If I try to commit through the command line, it fails as expected.  However, if I commit from egit, the hook is ignored and the changes get committed.

Does egit/jgit not recognize hooks yet?  Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did a quick google search... It looks like this is not currently supported. http://code.google.com/p/egit/issues/detail?id=105 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Original answer: June 2011)

[MatrixFrog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65977/matrixfrog) correctly points out to the [bug 299315](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315), which mentions those hooks aren't supported yet.

You also can explore the JGit repository, [now on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit), <del>which doesn't show any commit about hooks</del>.
And you can search for 'hook' in the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide): the notion of hook isn't mentioned either.

---

Update March 2015 (4 years later): as [MariuszS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516167/mariuszs) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered/6236026?noredirect=1#comment46847944_6236026), ["hook" is present in JGit](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=hook).

In 2015, there are works in progress to support those hooks:

- "[Introduce hook support into the FS implementations](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/40504/)"
- "[Support for the pre-commit hook](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/40506/)" (so not yet pre-receive hook)

Those should be in the upcoming JGit 3.7

---

Update Q4 2015, EGit 4.x does support hooks, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32462648/6309).

Comment: @MariuszS True, I have updated the answer. JGit 3.7 should start to support *some* hooks.

Comment: So does it support hooks now?

Comment: @jayarjo the pre-commit is supported. Others not so much: see their status at https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/q/project:jgit/jgit+hook

Comment: Now egit also supports hooks. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32462648

Comment: @AmitM Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

run: git commit -a ...

from the command line in your working directory if you can, the hook gets executed and all other eGit functionality will work as normal.