# Why does my Git post-receive hook not run when I push from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, jenkins

I have setup a basic `post-receive` hook on my Git repository:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/confirm-hook
/usr/bin/curl http://__server__/git/notifyCommit?url=file:///srv/git/repo.git
```

The point of this is to poll a Jenkins automatic build.

When I `git push` from the command line, the hook runs and a Jenkins poll is scheduled. I can confirm the hook itself has run by checking the modified timestamp of `/tmp/confirm-hook`.

However, when I push from within Eclipse (eg Team > Push to Upstream) the commit is sent to the repo, but the `post-receive` hook is not run. No scheduled poll and no updates to `/tmp/confirm-hook`.

Is this something peculiar about Eclipse's Git implementation? Or have I configured the hook incorrectly?

In case it makes a difference, the working copy and the repo are on the same computer using /local/path/syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this behaviour is due to Eclipse's use of Jgit, coupled with the repo being a local path.

As far as I can tell, when Eclipse pushes to a repo on a local path (`/path/to/repo` or `file:///path/to/repo`) all the functionality is provided by Jgit; the command line Git tool is not used. Jgit does not currently support git hooks.

When I changed the remote URL to use ssh:// syntax (connecting to the same local machine), the hooks do run even when Eclipse pushes the commits.

References:

- [Egit hooks do not get triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered)
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315

Comment: how and where do you need to change the repo to ssh:// ?

Comment: @Gavriel it's the remote URL, for the working copy, which needs changing. There's many ways you could do that; in this case, I would edit `.git/config` and replace `file:///` with `ssh://user@localhost/`.

Answer (score 1):

`post-receive` hook runs on the server where git repo you are pushing to exists. It has no link with which client you use to push to the repo - be it the command line, Eclipse or any other tool.

Make sure both the command line and Eclispe are pushing to the same repo, and that repo is the one where you have the hook installed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both Eclipse and the command line tool (and the repo, for that matter) are on the same computer and are definitely pushing to the same place. The commits all arrive, no matter which tool pushes them (I have checked `git log` religiously as I have been trouble-shooting this) but the `post-receive` script only runs when I push from the command line.

Comment: Do you use the same user when you are from the command line and from Eclipse ? try to chmod +x post-receive to allow everyone to execute. I often forgot that

Comment: @Asenar I am using the same user. The repo is also owned by the same user. Thanks for the thought, but I'm pretty sure now the issue is a flaw (or feature!) of Jgit.