# How can I change Signed-off-by Message of Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

EGit has the option add Signed-off-by message to any commit.
For a project I am crontibuting, it is required to have an extended Signed-off-by message. They require to have the github handle added.

```
Signed-off-by: Joe Smith <joe.smith@email.com> (github: github_handle)
```

How can I change the default message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be supported yet by egit.

[`org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitEditorPage.java`#L90](https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/52328d63fedcd812e4ea1c01b9196aa723588702/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/commit/CommitEditorPage.java#L90) shows a fixed template (hard-coded):

```java
private static final String SIGNED_OFF_BY = "Signed-off-by: {0} <{1}>"; //$NON-NLS-1$

private String getSignedOffByLine(PersonIdent person) {
    return MessageFormat.format(SIGNED_OFF_BY, person.getName(),
            person.getEmailAddress());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the source of Egit/Jgit and tweak the pre-commit message.

Pre-commit hooks were not supported in Egit see [Egit hooks do not get triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered) and [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/237571/)

But you can achieve this by plane/raw git. Refer this post [How to add Git's branch name to the commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894946/how-to-add-gits-branch-name-to-the-commit-message)