# Pre-commit hook works in Git bash not in EGit

Tags: hook, egit

Environment: EGit 4.0.1.201506240215-r on Windows 7

I can commit with Git bash and the pre-commit hook is invoked, but when I try to commit in EGit, the pre-commit hook is not invoked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Egit hooks do not get triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered)

Answer (score 0):

GIT hooks are nothing but scripts which are to be executed by /bin/sh. Which you cannot do since you are running on Windows OS and you don't have sh.exe.

Install Cygwin

Add the cygwin_root/bin to your PATH

Make sure you install GIT during the cygwin installation(Since git hook scripts will execute git commands)

Hope this will help

Comment: thank you, install cygin, it works.actually, msysgit has sh.exe, but egit only find sh.exe in cygwin/bin