# hook is not working eclipse egit client

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am trying to trigger a hook file at the time of commit, but this is not working in EGIT. The same hook file is being executed If I use git bash or tortoisegit. Am I missing anything in the installation? 
How to fix this. I appreciate your help. For your information, below are the details of my eclipse and eclipse git plugin[EGIT]

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200

and Eclipse EGit version:4.0.0.201506090130-r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of EGit (4.x) [support commit hooks](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1067404/). If you are on Mars you should already have it, if not try updating from EGit update site.

In order to run them on Windows you need unix-like bash. You can try with [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [Msys2](http://msys2.github.io/). Put the folder with `sh.exe` on your path and EGit should be able to run your hooks.

Comment: You are just awesome !!  I downloaded Git for Windows, and then I downloaded Eclipse Mars...    hooks are being triggered now... thanks again !

Comment: Can you please provide more details here?  I have Eclipse Neon on Windows 10 with Git for Windows 2.10.2 and it is NOT working.

Comment: I have just checked that latest Git for Windows only contains `git.exe`, `sh.exe` and `bash.exe`. However EGit checks if the environment supports hooks by checking if the file `cygpath.exe` is present somewhere on PATH. Simply add empty `cygpath.exe` file to your `/usr/bin` in Git for Windows folder and you should be fine. I don't think that `cygpath.exe` is itself required, so it can be an empty file.