# How to integrate git hooks with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, gerrit, githooks

I am trying to setup pre-commit hook which we have customized to our requirement .
It is working fine in git bash but it is unable to pick up the hook from eclipse .
How can I integrate or configure so the pre-commit hook gets invoked.

Comment: are you using the eclipse plugin?  What version of eclipse ? If you are using egit this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered

Comment: i am using   Eclipse 4.2 along with egit plugin.

Comment: is it still not supported with egit ?

Comment: Well it looked like resolved here : https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/40506/   Its says resolved on JGit. You may want to check using JGit .

Comment: We are using  JGit , but still its not being invoked

Comment: This question is answered in the following link: [Same Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440968/hook-is-not-working-eclipse-egit-client)