# Use Egit to launch pre-commit hook

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am working in Eclipse Mars (4.5.2) with EGit (4.1.1) on Windows8. 
I try to launch a pre-commit hook from within eclipse using GitForWindows.

I started the pre-commit file with: `#!/bin/sh`

and gave the `PATH` Variable GITFORWINDOWS with the path to the bin folder in which the sh.exe of my GitForWindows installation is stored (C:\Program Files\Git\bin).

If I do `git commit` in the GitBash, pre-commit is executed correctly, thus an error is thrown if a certain string is detected in the staged files. If I commit in Eclipse nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I tried it with Cygwin as well. While it is working from the cygwin terminal (as well as from the GitInWindows terminal) it is not working from within eclipse.

I set the `PATH` to `C:\cygwin64\bin` where the `sh.exe` is.

Can line returns be a problem? I have LF so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Egit hooks do not get triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered)

Comment: EGit and JGit support (some) hooks since 4.2. See here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315

Comment: In the duplicate you proposed I found no solution to my problem though! It only mentions that git hooks are implemented in EGit by now and should be working.

Comment: As I said in the above comment: EGit 4.1 does not yet support hooks. If you follow the link to [bug  299315](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=299315) in the answer, you'll read the EGit 4.2 has some support for hooks. But you are using EGit 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `PATH` variable for Cygwin worked in the end. I had to restart the computer though.

It still is not working for GitForWindows. This might be due to the fact that JGit has a `FS_Win32_Cygwin` class which extracts the path to the `sh.exe` from the 'PATH' variable. Such a class might not exist for GitForWindows (yet). More information [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1067404/).

The version (4.1.1) of my EGit doesn't seem to play a role.

Answer (score 0):

To run hooks from with in Eclipse (Egit) you need to do the following:

Hooks are implemented as scripts which need to be executed by "/bin/sh".

But on a plain windows machine you don't have a `sh.exe`.
So, you need to install `cygwin` and add `<cygwin_root>/bin` to your `PATH`.

Make sure that during cygwin installation you also install git (because the hook scripts want to execute git commands).

Comment: In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440968/hook-is-not-working-eclipse-egit-client) GitForWindows is named as alternative for Cygwin. What is the difference between the two of them? I found a sh.exe in GitForWindows as well

Comment: Since version 2 there is a new windows client names GitForWindows which is an alternative git windows client. It has some special code for windows and it can be found here: https://github.com/git-for-windows

Comment: I would like to use GitForWindows instead of Cygwin, as it is installed already. If it is an equivalent alternative I should be able to use it for the hooks, setting the `PATH` variable to its `sh.exe`. Still it doesn't work.