# How to format code according to google java format

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, code-formatting

**Current state:**

I have a project which is build with: Java 1.8.161, Maven 3.3.9, SpringBoot 2.0.1, tools: Jenkins and GitLab. I would like to use [google java format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) as a standard for whole team.

**My investigation / solution:**

During the investigation I found [solution](https://github.com/coveo/fmt-maven-plugin), which sounds really easy. Just update pom file with:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.coveo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fmt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>format</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And it works. If I run compile, package, verify, install or deploy Maven lifecycle the code is formatted.

**Question:**

How can I run this after i.e. each commit for all team members without any extra steps in their IDEA? Because right now, I need to run Maven before each commit. But during the run of an application it is not necessary, so the team can avoid it.. Which of course will lead to problems with history in git.

Comment: I would recommend to define a coding style in the IDE and only check the style in your build best would be something like CI solution like Jenkins and in case it does not follow fail the build that will train the people...(see for example checkstyle-maven-plugin...)

Comment: Why don't you just use their IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise It looks good I will definitely try it! Thank you!

Comment: @Meo Because this will increase work for all of the team members. If I will just update pom file and check code then on jenkins there is no more work. Team will teach, that before commit it is necessary to check code style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can let **pre-commit hook** trigger formatter for files staged for commit.

[git-code-format-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin) uses [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) formatter and can install client-side pre-commit git hook during compile phase. It [requires](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin/issues/7) Maven 3.5.x, which should be enforced.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
      <artifactId>git-code-format-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>VERSION</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>install-hooks</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>VERSION</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <rules>
              <requireMavenVersion>
                <version>[3.5.4,)</version>
              </requireMavenVersion>
            </rules>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Point to *standalone* Maven in IDE as *git-code-format-maven-plugin* does not play along nicely with embedded Maven.

`mvn compile` to get hook installed. For *IDEA*, that's it.

As *git-code-format-maven-plugin* only formats changed files (which is good), it is probably good to format whole project upfront once (`mvn git-code-format:format-code -Dgcf.globPattern=**/*`).

### Workaround for Eclipse

Because of a bug in EGit, which sometimes ignores Git hooks completely, developers using *Eclipse on Windows* should have Cygwin in PATH. An empty `cygpath.exe` will do. Run 'Command Prompt' as a administrator and execute `C:\>echo "" > /"Program Files"/Git/bin/cygpath.exe` (kudos to [hook is not working eclipse egit client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440968/hook-is-not-working-eclipse-egit-client/32462648#comment72357381_32462648)).

Reboot.

### A note on java import statements ordering

Optimise imports or reformat in IDE or reformat with plugins, can lead to changes in imports ordering. A nasty surprise if an older version of *git-code-format-maven-plugin* is being used together with *fmt-maven-plugin* (to format or validate code later in CI, for example).

- [git-code-format-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Cosium/git-code-format-maven-plugin) will sort imports (since version 1.20)
- [fmt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/coveo/fmt-maven-plugin) will always sort imports
- [googleformatter-maven-plugin](https://github.com/talios/googleformatter-maven-plugin) can optionally sort imports (not per default)

Comment: maven-git-code-format always sorts the import statements since 1.20 ;)

Comment: maven-git-code-format also supports upfront format by using `mvn git-code-format:format-code -DglobPattern=**/*`

Comment: @RédaHousniAlaoui seems your plugin was renamed. Luckyly Github still finds it by the old link. Anyway, you may want to update names and links in your answer ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Wlad. I submitted an update :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to run this formatter after each developer commit, you will have to first have a Jenkins commit hook in place, that will trigger a Jenkins build. One of the phases of the build, should execute the fmt-maven-plugin's (or any others) `check` functionality in order to ensure that the code is properly formatted.

### Adding a webhook

First thing to do is add a webhook that will trigger a Jenkins build after every commit in your git repository. You can find how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794568/how-to-configure-git-post-commit-hook). For Gitlab specific instructions, [this post from medium](https://medium.com/@teeks99/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-and-gitlab-fa770c62e88a) may be helpful.

### Executing the check

This can be done by executing the `check` goal on the `fmt-maven-plugin`

Maven acceps either `<plugin-prefix>:<goal>` or `<plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>` as a means of calling a plugin goal, so for your specific problem, you can run:

```
mvn fmt:check
```

That being said, you will have to add a Jenkins build step, that will run the mentioned command. Step 5 from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm) shows you how to add a build step.

Hope that this actually helps :D

Answer (score 0):

> I need to run Maven before each commit

You do not need to run multiple maven goals. For eg no need to run `maven install` for the formatting to take place. A simple `maven compile` will formate the classes.