# Egit in Eclipse doesn't execute pre-commit hook

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am trying to plug `egit` in Eclipse to run my pre-commit hooks. But it doesn't seem to work.

I found a similar [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440968/hook-is-not-working-eclipse-egit-client/32462648#32462648) but that doesn't seem to be working in my case.

Here is what all I got as required tools

1. GitForWindows in place
2. Pre-commit hooks configured

   - Works well from command line and Tortoise git as well.

As suggested from answers and comments section in the aforementioned linked question, I did add the `cygpath.exe` empty file in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and put this in path. Also, I verified that `cygpath.exe` is already available in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` alongside `ssh.exe, bash.exe`.

Again, both `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` are added to System variables and user variables under Environment variables in my Windows 10.

**Additional info**

- Eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
- Eclipse Egit : 5.x version

Comment: You will find more information in the Eclipse forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1067404&goto=1698542&#msg_1698542

Comment: @howlger: Thanks for link, but that didn't help

Answer (score 3):

Hooks in EGit/JGit on Windows do not require Git for Windows to be installed (JGit implements Git in Java, it does not redirect to the command line Git).

The **installation directory of `cygpath.exe` must be in the `PATH`** because Cygwin is required on Windows to execute a Git hook (which is bash scripts).

In your case, the empty `cygpath.exe` file will cause the wrong directory to be used.

For more details see [this Eclipse forum discussion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1067404&goto=1698542) or look into the [JGit Java code here](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/HEAD/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/FS_Win32_Cygwin.java).

See also this [blog post by Christoph Zauner with more details](https://zauner.nllk.net/post/0001-git-hooks-currently-supported-by-jgit/) (note, the list of supported hooks is outdated, but the concepts are still the same).

Comment: @howgler: I configured hooks in another directory instead of default `.hooks/` and updated in `config`, but now to make egit plugin understand, just placed pre-commit file in `.hooks` and it worked partially. BUT, my powershell console output is not displayed in eclipse egit alert box. It simply says, 
       ` Rejected by "pre-commit" hook.`

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, this has not yet been implemented. See [Eclipse bug 536659](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536659) (you might vote for this bug and comment there).

Comment: This blog deep-dives into the issue and is quite worth a read to better understand: https://zauner.nllk.net/post/0001-git-hooks-currently-supported-by-jgit/

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the link. I have added it to my answer.